# Reference Request: Semi-Rings and Rings (System of Sets, not Algebraic Structures)

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, universal-algebra

I studied Probability Theory (from a Measure Theory viewpoint) using only Sigma-Algebras.

Recently, I got a book about measure theory that starts from Semi-Rings, but it's presentation is too compact. Anyone got a suggestion on a good book that shows measures on Semi-Rings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 3 of Aliprantis and Burkinshaw [Principles of Real Analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Principles_of_real_analysis.html?id=uC3vAAAAMAAJ) treats measures on semirings.

Comment: I'm looking at a used copy on Amazon, and it looks interesting. Includes a chapter on set theory and a chapter on point set topology.

Comment: Yes, it's an excellent book for self-study, and there's a companion volume of solutions, so you can check your work.